# Error of can not invoke method or retrieve property from a null object

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

I am using C# Winforms and CSOM - am attempting to return the version history with this method. I have verified that all variables being passed in hold an appropriate and correct value. But once the ExecuteQuery() line is hit the error is thrown

```
Public static DataSet Gethistory(string siteurl, string listName, int Id)
{
  Using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
  {
    Var file = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName).GetItemId(Id).File;
    Var versions = file.Versions;
    Ctx.Load(file);
    Ctx.Load(versions);
    Ctx.Load(versions, vs => vs.Include(v => v.CreatedBy))
    Ctx.ExecuteQuery();
  }
  For each (FileVersion fv in versions)
  {
      Console.writeline(fv.createdby.title);
       Console.writeline(fv.checkincomment);
      Console.writeline(fv.iscurrentversion);
   }
}
```

Sorry for any typos this was posted mobile!

Edit to show updated code:

```
Public static DataSet GetHistory(string siteUrl, string listName, isn’t id)
{
    Using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
    {
      Web web = ctx.Web;
      ctx.Load(web);
      ctx.Load(web.Lists);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
      var item = list.GetItemById(id);
      ctx.Load(item);
      ctx.Load(item.File);
      ctx.Load(item.File.Versions);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      var versions = item.File.Versions;
      foreach (FileVersion fileVersion in versions)
      {

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code snippet to get the file versions

```
    siteUrl= "https://server";
    Using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
    {
      ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
      Web web = ctx.Web;
      ctx.Load(web);
      ctx.Load(web.Lists);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
      var item = list.GetItemById(id);
      ctx.Load(item);
      ctx.Load(item.File);
      ctx.Load(item.File.Versions);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      var versions = item.File.Versions;
      foreach (FileVersion fileVersion in versions)
      {

      }
}
```

Comment: I alter syntax to be var file = ctx.Web.Lists.Getbytitle(list name).Getitembyid(is).file; ctx.load(file); ctx.executequery(); and have same error thrown.  Object returned by the following call stack is null. “File getitembyid getbytitle”

Comment: Ctx. Load(ctx. Web) before initialize var file im writing from cell phone so revise the code

Comment: I add line ctx.load(ctx.Web); before var file... and same error

Comment: @user2676140 please check my update

Comment: That gets me to the foreach loop and throws the error - the collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed.

Comment: @user2676140 should add Ctx.ExecuteQuery(); line

Comment: If I add ctx.ExecuteQuery(); directly after the var version line, I get an error of can not invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. File getitembyid, getbytitle

Comment: @user2676140 add it before var version as an the example above

Comment: Same error if I move the ExecuteQuery above the line.

Comment: I verified the list name is correct. I can pull other info for fields in this list, this one is giving me issues. How would I do the debugging to get relevant info?

Comment: @user2676140 update your question with your latest code updates and let me see

Comment: See my edit to OP

Comment: hi @user2676140 actually it matches with the sample above i tested it and couldn't generate any issues

Comment: Is there anyway I can provide pertinent debug information for you to assist further?  I want to view all of the fileversion info for the ID being passed

Comment: @user2676140 i added the tested code

Comment: I get an error of the type or namespace NetworkCredentials could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: @user2676140 what type of the application are using? and what's the SP version ?

Comment: C# console - I believe it is 2013. I have this syntax now ..... SecureString theSecureString = new NetworkCredential(“”,”password”);  ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnline redentials(“Domain/username”, theSe ureString); and get an error of ‘username argument is invalid’

Comment: @user2676140 NetworkCredentials  neet to add Using System.Net; as a reference

Comment: I added ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(“Domain/user”,”password”); and I get same debug error of can not invoke method or retrieve property from null object.

Comment: @user2676140 use new NetworkCredential(“user”,”password”, "domain");  or new NetworkCredential(@“Domain\user”,”password”); use the first one better

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76186/discussion-on-answer-by-a-saeed-error-of-can-not-invoke-method-or-retrieve-prope).

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically for the properties which you are trying to load as part of the version collection

```
Console.writeline(fv.checkincomment);
Console.writeline(fv.iscurrentversion);
```

Since these are not being initialized in as part of your include statement. Please try below code and check if it works:

```
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
var versions = list.GetItemById(2).File.Versions;
context.Load(list, li => li.Title, li => li.EnableVersioning);
context.Load(versions, vc => vc.Include(v => v.CreatedBy, v => v.IsCurrentVersion, v => v.CheckInComment));
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine("List Title: {0}, List Version Control Status: {1}", list.Title, list.EnableVersioning);
Console.WriteLine("Version count: {0}", versions.Count);

foreach (var version in versions)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This version was created by: {0}", version.CreatedBy.Title);
    Console.WriteLine(version.IsCurrentVersion);
    Console.WriteLine(version.CheckInComment);
 }
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I get debug error on ctx.ExecuteQuery(); of can not invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. file GetItemById GetByTitke

Comment: The error has something to do with the ctx object. Try passing the credentials 
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(O365_UserName, SecureString); (***Secure String here is your O365 password***)
If you are using On-Prem then you might have to use NetworkCredentials

Comment: I get compile error of can not convert string to system.security.securestring

Comment: I get a 401 Unathorized error?

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/23/call-o365-using-csom-with-a-console-application/) to connect console application to O365. Make sure you use the O365_UserName as (abc@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com).

The 401 suggests that you do not have access to read the list. Please check if you have access to the site/list.

Comment: Yes, I have access to add/edit the list. I am able to connect wo providing username and password to read data, just this multi line append text field is giving me a major headache